Can one determine the number of forecast/prediction steps in a VAR on a priori grounds?
Context of my question: I am running a vector autoregression (VAR) model using two time-series of equal length (n ~ 750 data points). The lag was chosen based on the Bayes information criterion (BIC) and I finally run Granger Causality (GC) between both time-series.
For the moment, I trained the VAR on 80% of the data, hence leaving the last 20% for testing or prediction. Since both time-series were non-stationary, I applied first-order differencing on both of them for training the VAR and before running GC. Of note, the original time-series (non-differenced) include no repetitive temporal pattern, that is, they include no seasonality etc.
I would finally like to evalutate how well the prediction of the VAR works and came across the idea of using the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) between the actual and predicted values of the time-series in question (let's say time-series B predicted and granger caused by time-series A).
"Problem": I plotted the predicted vs. the actual values and realized that only the first 4 to 5 values are predicted well. The next time points starting with the 6. value predict non-sense. After time point 5, the prediction converges into a horizontal straight line, that is, it looks like it just continues to predict the mean of the (differenced) time-series without approximately following the real temporal pattern of the data anymore.
Questions: I have two questions.

Is it normal that a VAR trained on ~600 data points (80% of the data) can, depending on the dynamics or properties of the time-series, only predict 4 to 5 values well? Is this expected especially since my data is based on a process that has no repetitive temporal structure or patterns anyway?
Most importantly, is there a way to a priori determine or select the number of steps that I would like to predict? Is there a statistical test or tool to select the number of forecast steps quantitatively, or does this always depend on the context and subjective criteria? Question two is important for me concerning RMSE. If I pick the number of forecasted steps a posteriori, based on a visual inspection of the real vs. predicted values, it feels like cheating concerning the RMSE estimation.

